# SQL Server part number searching with possible variations on nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, pattern-matching

I've been tasked with looking into a part number matching issue, the basics of which there are several different ranges with different patterns for the part numbers; for example `0-732-012` might be stored in the database but the user might then search using `0732012` or `0.732.012`, it could also be that the part numbers themselves have been added wrong in some cases (so there would be `0732012` as valid entry as well).

There is also some alphanumeric part numbers mixed in as well so `0732012KG` for example.

My question is this then, is there an efficient way of checking numerical codes? Either by stripping or ignoring the non-numerical values when attempting to match?

The data is stored in SQL Server 2008 so it does have the capacity for RegEx should that be required.

Comment: There are a number of ways. First of all how is the number stored in the DB exactly? Will the alphas always be on the end of the part number? With all the specifics about how the number is stored I need. Also will customers or whoever is searching the dat search for 0-732-012 or 0.732.012 or could it be 07-320-12 or 0732.0.12 or any variation?

Comment: I'd ensure that the data is normalized and in the future saved in the right format. This way, many many issues won't occur in the first place.

Comment: Sorry should have said, the Numbers are stored as nVarchar(255) values and I've had a double check, the Alphas can appear at different points in the code (different manufactures with different part number systems. 

As for the variations from the search values, yes - But I was going to strip any spaces and special characters since I was thinking that should make things easier, which has just given me an idea for matching....

Comment: If it is stored as VARCHAR, you might consider using LIKE. This is very slow though.

Comment: @Jan I wish I could but even the customer admits it's a mess but since it's what the supplier gives them it's difficult to go and normalise the data (seriously, some of the suppliers give a parts listing with the dashes on the part codes, then provides price lists without or vice versa because....reasons....)

Comment: A regex like `([-.\d]+)` might probably suit your needs. It looks for a dash, a point or a number one or more times and captures them in a group. Get rid of the non numerical characters in a script language then.

Comment: I've already had a try with that same RegEx but no dice since there's still the input to match against (basically having to apply the RegEx to both the row and the input and checking against the RegEx outputs) which would only find 1 out of a few possible matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do.
Strip all dashes, spaces, special characters from both entry and field level (only in the comparison).
much faster than using a like.

Comment: Funnily enough I just came to the same conclusion so I've already started on a process to add a new column and clean it out.

Comment: @Chris M my initial instinct is to do it without adding a column.  but if your table is huge and need to add an index on the clean column then yes... I would also add a column if it doesn't cause any issue.

Comment: It's 300K+ records so running checks on the fly everytime would put an unnecessary load on the server everytime the search is run.

I've added the extra column in and so far it seems to be working without issue, so I'm going to close the issue.